# Find the Jquery version using normal Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way to find the version of Jquery using normal plain javascript.
I know to do this using JQuery itself by using the following code.

```
jQuery.fn.jquery;
```

or

```
$().jquery;
```

But this wont works for me beacuse I am not allowed to use Jquery code. Please suggest any alternative methods using only plain javascript.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I am not allowed to use Jquery code"... then why do you (a) care what version is available? (b) even have it included in your page?

Comment: if you can't use jQuery you cannot check the version that you are using not?

Comment: Is your assignment some kind of punishment?

Comment: I really dont understand why u made down vote, I just want to know a solution. If I want to answer your queries it will take one big page.

Comment: If it's a homework, you should add the appropriate tag `homework`, so we answerers know, where the problem stems from.

Comment: Do you mean you want to check what is the latest version of jquery available without including jquery in your code? Like you are building an application that tells you the latest jquery version ??

Comment: U guys dont understand my situation, I am working in such a critical situation and my project rquirement demands that. Thats why I asked. If this is not the correct place please forgive me, I wont ask more questions.
Thanks to all...

Comment: The fact is "normal javascript" is jQuery. jQuery is still Javascript as is any other Javascript framework. A reference of "normal javascript" vs using jQuery would usually be focused on event handling and traversing the DOM. Just calling `jQuery.fn.query` is "normal javascript". @simon is correct in asking if the work you're doing is some kind of punishment. It sounds like a stupid unanswerable riddle that when thought about correctly is semantically incorrect. Whatever you're working on, fix the issue of a requirement like this instead of working to that requirement.

Comment: What you want cannot really be done (although the opinions on this may differ, as you see from Boldewyn's answer), it's like saying "lift yourself up with your own hands". I would discuss the requirement to clarify it.

Comment: I will tell you the details. I am using normal JS code to load a jquery file. Before calling this I need to check already any older version of JQuery is available here. So my first script is written in normal JS, from here itself I need to do this checking. I hope my question is clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a variable and try to get the version using

```
var jVersion;
jVersion = jQuery.fn.jquery;
console.log(jVersion);
```

Use this method if you are using any normal JS code

Comment: for example
    var jVersion;
    if (typeof jQuery !== 'undefined') {  
       jVersion = jQuery.fn.jquery;
       console.log(jVersion);
    }

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery.fn.jquery
```

is a plain JavaScript property. This has nothing to do with 'using jQuery', so that's a proper 'JavaScript' way of getting jQuery's version.

*Edit:* If you just need to check, if a version of jQuery already exists, you can simply test for `window.jQuery`:

```
if ("jQuery" in window) {
    // get its version:
    var jquery_version = window.jQuery.fn.jquery;
}
```

(If you haven't seen that before: `window.jQuery` is basically the same as a global variable with the name `jQuery` in most cases.)

Comment: I didn't really know that this is proper Javascript.
Thanks Boldewyn.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by 'jquery code' - it's all just JavaScript.

This is how you reference the JavaScript function named '$':

```
$
```

This is how you call that function:

```
$()
```

This is how you access the `jquery` property of the return value of that function:

```
$().jquery
```

Which gives you what you need!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you can't use the word `$` or `jQuery` in your code?

What about:

```
window[String.fromCharCode(36)]()[String.fromCharCode(106,113,117,101,114,121)]
```